# calculating rate of change for a vector of numbers

Tags: r

I want to calculate the rate of change in a vector of numbers, however the denominator for the calculation should be the very first number in the vector.

I can calculate the rate of change between the vector of numbers but can't come-up with a way to make the very first number the constant denominator for the calculation

I don't want this answer

```
x <- seq(5, 5.5, 0.1)
TTR::ROC(x, type = "discrete")
[1]         NA 0.02000000 0.01960784 0.01923077 0.01886792 0.01851852
```

Instead I want to generate

```
0.02    0.019607843 0.019230769 0.018867925 0.018518519
```

Would anyone know a handy super fast function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to define your own function

```
rr1 <- function(x) diff(x) / x[-length(x)]
rr1(x)
#[1] 0.02000000 0.01960784 0.01923077 0.01886792 0.01851852
```

Or with a classic `for` loop

```
rr2 <- function(x) {
    r <- numeric(length(x) - 1)
    for (i in 1:(length(x) - 1)) r[i] <- (x[i + 1] - x[i]) / x[i]
    r
}
rr2(x)
#[1] 0.02000000 0.01960784 0.01923077 0.01886792 0.01851852
```

And a `microbenchmark` comparison of both methods for a larger vector `x` with `10^4` entries

```
x <- seq(1, 1000, length.out = 10^4)
library(microbenchmark)
res <- microbenchmark(
    rr1 = rr1(x),
    rr2 = rr2(x))
#Unit: microseconds
# expr      min       lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
#  rr1  157.596  190.554  518.0451  472.6565  501.5825  9565.411   100  a
#  rr2 2057.669 2098.655 2397.8759 2121.2795 2227.8395 10124.874   100   b
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I have a few million rows to perform this calculation on. Would there be an already existing function in C or something like that?

Comment: @cephalopod The `diff(x) / x[-length(x)]` method should be very fast; a few million rows is not a lot. I don't know what runs under the hood of `diff` but I imagine it being highly optimised code. Running `rr1` on a vector with 10 million entries gives a result pretty much instantaneously.